# What does the size used in ffmpeg logging indicate?

Tags: ffmpeg, size, rtsp

I am using FFmpeg to read a RTSP stream.

FFmpeg sometimes gives a error message 'Past duration x.xx to large' including the following data in the logging:

```
frame=174635061 fps=24 q=-0.0 size=875425493kB time=312:09:56.45 bitrate=32350.1kbits/s dup=3424 drop=5
```

In my case 'size' is huge, I would like to understand what 'size' is indicating.
I have not been able to find a answer in the documentation at http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

FFmpeg version: 3.2.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` represents the total byte size of the generated output file.

You can ignore the *Past duration x.xx to large* messages, they were downgraded in log visibility in ver 4.1. You should upgrade ffmpeg to 4.3 or recent git.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I am not storing the file, so this is actually only the total amount of data passed through? So can I ignore this?

Comment: Yes, but protocol and network overhead isn't included.